# Here API sdk for flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, here-api, flutter-animation

I'm currently working on integrating the HERE API into my Flutter app. I've installed the HERE SDK for Flutter, but I'm encountering an issue where there's no pubspec.yaml file in the SDK directory (C:\Users\NeuerBenutzer\Desktop\Here_Api\Plugins\here_sdk). Typically, Flutter projects rely on pubspec.yaml to manage dependencies, and its absence is hindering the integration process.

Could anyone provide guidance on how to proceed with integrating the HERE SDK into a Flutter project despite the absence of a pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: Have you followed the instructions here? https://www.here.com/docs/bundle/sdk-for-flutter-explore-developer-guide/page/topics/quick-start.html#step-1-create-a-flutter-project